# Django comments taking out new lines

Tags: django, newline, django-comments

So I've been working with Django-comments and I'm pretty happy, but a friend pointed out that when he posted something that was longer and had new lines, Django took them out.

For example if I posted:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Then it would be saved and displayed as:

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Has anyone using Django realized this and figured out how to get around Django taking out new lines? I've poked around a bit in Django-comments code but haven't found anything yet that could be overridden.

Thanks

Comment: yeah, I've tried putting <br/> in the comment and it does nothing. Plus I don't want users having to put <br/> in their comments when they want a new line anyway. That'd be silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`linebreaks` and `linebreaksbr` filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#linebreaks)? Instead of using the `render_comment_list` tag, you'd use [the `get_comment_list` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#rendering-a-custom-comment-list) to get a list of `Comment` objects, then you could pass the `comment` attribute through the appropriate filter.

Comment: It's funny but I'm pretty sure I've read that before. It's exactly what I needed. Thanks.